# Update column in Access using query in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to update a column by adding a value in Access:

```
update table1 set column1 = column1+value
```

In the above, if column1 is null, then the table is not updated.

I need a function like in SQL Server:

```
update table1 set column1 = isnull(column1,0) + value
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not give a data type for column1. The string concatenator is & not +, so consider:

```
UPDATE Table1  
SET Table1.AText = [AText] & "A", 
    Table1.ANumber = Nz([ANumber],0)+1;
```

In both these examples, the column (field) will be updated even if it is null.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no option for it in query if you are using Access as database (Backend)